# http status 408 in j_security_check using JBoss

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, struts, http-error

Currently I'm facing strange problem. I have one demo application which just authenticate user from database and shows welcome page.

The problem is if I keep login page open and then after restarting server, try to login using the same page which is opened earlier, screen shown me `HTTP Status 408 - The time allowed for the login process has been exceeded.` error.

I tried the suggested changed in [HTTP Status 408 error during login with domain forwarding set up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727668/http-status-408-error-during-login-with-domain-forwarding-set-up) link but it's not working.

This is my login page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store,no-cache,must-revalidate"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"/>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action='<%= response.encodeURL("j_security_check") %>' id="login" >
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="j_username" id="username" autofocus />

        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="j_password" id="password" />

        <button type="submit" class="primary" name="Submit">Log in</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to debug but request is not coming through server to controller. So I'm guessing something is wrong with jboss server. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is this similar to you problem? http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.tomcat.user/122471

Comment: Yes, it's the same one and it's due to session expiry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case , I added to login page.

```
setInterval(function(){
        location.reload(true); //reload each 5 minutes
    },5*60*1000);
```

Hope this help.

Comment: yeah this could be helpful if posted earlier :). Though I've redirected user to session timeout page on 408.